# Return type based on typeof parameter value

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I am creating a function that takes two parameters a `key` and a value to `cast` the result to. So, I created an `type` that limits the values that an item can be cast to. I would also like this to be the return type, however based on `EnvCast`, it is prefixed with `typeof`, so the way that I am using it, it says that it should return a `typeof x`.

How can I return a type based on the value of `cast`? So if `cast('my_key', Number)` the return type will be a `Number` and not `typeof Number`?.

```js
declare type EnvCast = typeof Number | typeof Boolean | typeof String;

export function env<T extends EnvCast>(key: string, cast?: EnvCast): T {
    const result = (process.env[key] ? process.env[key] : '') as string;
    if (!cast) { return result; }
    return cast(result);
}
```

Edit:

I guess I could do something like this (Is there a way to do it without this)?:

```
export function env(key: string, cast: typeof Number): number;
export function env(key: string, cast: typeof Boolean): boolean;
export function env(key: string, cast: typeof String): string;
export function env(key: string, cast: EnvCast): any {
   // Body of function...
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to do `Number | Boolean | String`. I'm still new with Typescript, because `typeof Number === "number"`, etc... Unless you intended for `env` to return a string?

Comment: No, using that syntax means that the value will be `123`, and I don't want a physical number there I want the function type `Number` so that I can call that function in my function.

Comment: you could declare the return type of your env function as :ReturnType<T>  .. that might be closer to what you need but still lacking as the return type will be String|Number|Boolean. not sure ts compiler is smart enough to resolve this but it's interesting use case, will monitor this question :)

Comment: What do you want typescript to do?
keep track of type after this function?
or just not show errors?

Comment: @OdedBD I want to get the return type so variables are set to that type after return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cast` argument type could be represented by a type parameter `C` that extends `EnvCast`. Then, `env` function returns [`ReturnType<C>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypet), which basically is `number | boolean | string` (`InstanceType<C>` would give us the primitive boxed type, which is [no good](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#number-string-boolean-symbol-and-object)):

```
export function env<C extends EnvCast>(key: string, cast?: C): ReturnType<C> {
  const result = (process.env[key] ? process.env[key] : '') as string;
  if (!cast) { throw new Error() /* or something else you want to do here */ }
  return cast(result) as ReturnType<C>;
}

const r1 = env("myKey", Number) // number
const r2 = env("myKey", Boolean) // boolean
const r3 = env("myKey", String) // string
const r4 = env("myKey", Array) // error
const r5 = env("myKey", Date) // error
```

[Sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=17&ssc=1&pln=5&pc=1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAXAngBwQUQHYDcDCUAzovALxJogD2AZvAHICuAtgEYgzwA%20F6t8AISpUIIKFm69qdAMqIYASywBzANwBYAFBbQkWAjBUsxeKhhUwIQoQBc8cci1aQAD1RUYJGoyxhECo3gQXAAePCCXRGDgQnhsfCJEAD4ACgBrEGQ7YkUVABp4MESAfjs8AEo7ACUQREYYLAAVSjCk%20ABvLXhCoxM4QkYIEnIUswsrQgA6YJwAbQzkAF14YtNzS2tp3HnM5bsAcn3y%201icpTUu%20AU6FIBCIuJj9qQAC3MAd3gsEE%20MGHMYCljgB6ABU8A88EIVGYtRe5yCEEICGQVEY8He4hIiCo8GAuJeHAQoOB8AAvpc4HUGoVEil%20oNEMciPAatSmi08EkNJoKdpNIZjCQYABGMhBXApABEzGQAGlMlKCkw2BwQaSsCx2DAtIK%20gAmcUzaWyhXIJWCYSicTq%20CsK1iLC63rCgDMRslMvlioKclyyltZxUzqF8BgABYPTgTd7zQUAIL-KDIW0cAEhvoAVijMbNFoAIlAouUM8KAGw5r15goAeVYACtwEynJogA)

Answer (score 0):

how about using [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) function

```
function env<T>(key: string, cast: T): T {

}
```

the usage will be like this

```
const x = env<number>('' , 10); // x will be of type number
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat different approach, if I understood your requirement, this might work:

```
declare type EnvCast = Number | Boolean | String;
export function env<T extends EnvCast>(key: string, cast?: (string)=>T):T {
    const result = (process.env[key] ? process.env[key] : '') as string;
    return cast(result);
}
const x= env('42',Number)  //x is number here
```